# using the prefix "Self"

Tags: meaning, grammar, meaning-in-context, prefixes

I came up with the following structure , trying to say that everyone should take their own precautionary measures.

**The structure:**

**Every one should take a self-precautionary measures.**

My question: is using the prefix "self" applicable ???

Comment: You should not use 'a' before measures (plural).

Comment: self-precautionary ain't great.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a better way to say it:

> Everyone should take precautionary measures to protect themselves.

The sentence you gave has a big problem:  it seems that you want to protect people from themselves.  On the other hand, you might be onto something!

Unfortunately, "self" does not make a good prefix for "precautionary".

Answer (score 0):

oneself. To mean a set of measure chosen individually one might s"self-precautionary measures." would mean precautions **against** oneself. To mean a set of individually chosen precautions, one might write:

> Every one should take self-chosen precautionary measures.

The comment by @Michael Harvey is correct that one should not use the indefinite article "a" in this structure.